# MATLAB: Finding minimal pixel values from a video

Tags: matlab, video-processing

I'm trying to write some MATLAB code such that given a monochromatic video, It needs to produce a image such that each pixel of the image equals the minimal value that said pixel takes in the video. As an example the pixel (200,300) will equal the min value that pixel (200,300) through the course of the video. I have written some code to do this however it's terribly inefficient. Any comments to improve my code would be appriciated

```
hologramVideo = VideoReader('test.mp4')
mkdir('images')
frames = int16(hologramVideo.Duration * hologramVideo.FrameRate)
imageValues = cell(frames, 1);
ii = 1;

while hasFrame(hologramVideo) 
   imageValues{ii} = im2uint8(rgb2gray(readFrame(hologramVideo)));
   ii = ii + 1;
end

newImage = zeros(512)
currentMin = 255
currentVal = 0

x = 1;
y = 1;

for x = 1:512
    for y = 1:512
        currentMin = 0;
        for i = 1:frames
            currentImg = imageValues(i,1,1);
            currentVal = currentImg{1,1}(x,y)
            if currentVal < currentMin;
              currentMin = currentVal;
            end
        end
        newImage(x,y) = currentMin;
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have a file to test, but the main bottleneck is in how you store the images. Rather than storing them in a cell array, you are better off storing them in a 3D-array:

```
imageValues = zeros([Nframes, 512, 512]);
ii=1;
while hasFrame(hologramVideo) 
   imageValues(ii,:,:) = im2uint8(rgb2gray(readFrame(hologramVideo)));
   ii = ii + 1;
end
```

That would make the remainder of the code very easy and vectorized (i.e. fast):

```
newImage = squeeze(min(imageValues,[],1));
```